# How application server runs multiple applications?

Tags: java, application-server

I've been looking for a while for such sort of information but i couldn't find a clear answer.

What exact mechanism application servers use to execute several (web)applications isolated?
For instance how do they manage static fields isolation?

I can imagine several solutions:

- [isolation API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Isolation_API);
- [bootstrapping](http://blog.markturansky.com/archives/21);
- tricks with class loaders (using thread context class loader);
- running several jvm instances.

But what do they use in reality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To separate applications, application servers indeed use separate ClassLoaders to distinguish classes (and their static fields) from each other.

JBoss for example is using a [Unified Class Loader](http://www.jroller.com/bsnyder/entry/jboss_unified_classloader_hell_docs) (UCL) since v4.

Comment: Do all of them use the same approach? What about WebSphere or Glassfish?

Comment: More or less, many of them seem to migrate (internally) to OSGi anyway, which is also based on separate ClassLoaders. None of which i'm aware of uses separated JVMs (except cloud solutions?) or "isolation api" - whatever that may be.